# Preventing default behaviour of Return(Enter), Up and Down Arrow keys for a ListView in XAML/C# (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-10, uwp

When a listview has focus, the default behaviour of an enter key press is to pick the first element of the listview, Up and down arrow keys scrolls the listview. I am trying to prevent this default behaviour and hook up my custom logic.

I am able to implement Access keys using KeyDown for a listview as follows:

Code behind approach:

```
CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += KeyDownHandler;
```

MVVM approach:

```
<ListView SelectedIndex="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Triggering the Keydown property:

```
<core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="KeyDown">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind VMDataContext.KeyDownCommand}" />
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
```

And used behaviours to scroll the scrollbar of the listview to the selected index:

```
<corebehaviors:ListViewScrollBehaviour SelectedIndex="{x:Bind IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The above handlers are getting triggered when the listview doesn't have focus. When the listview has focus, the default behaviour of arrow up, down and Enter key is getting triggered and not my attached behaviour. Is there a way to prevent the default behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider extending the `ListView` control and overriding the `OnKeyDown` handler.

```
public class ExtendedListView : ListView
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter || e.Key == VirtualKey.Up || e.Key == VirtualKey.Down)
        {
            return;
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin! It worked perfectly for Enter Key and not for Up and Down. It was weird as the breakpoints are not getting hit for up and down arrow keys. I also tried overriding the OnKeyUp function and observed the same behaviour.

Comment: BTW, you might want to call `e.Handled = true;` in some cases instead of `return`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(ListView_KeyDown);

private void ListView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        //do ur stuff
}
```

It would be a better approach to work with `PreviewKeyDown` event instead of `KeyDown`

Comment: ListView_KeyDown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args) can take only parameters of CoreWindow and KeyEventArgs. I am unable to use PreviewKeyDown as well. Not sure if that is available for WinRT apps.

Answer (score 1):

the Enter Key is a so called [VirtualKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/BR241812(v=win.10).aspx?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.System.VirtualKey)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) (click Link to see MSDN docs). This should get it done:

```
        private void UIElement_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
            {

            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As mentioned, this keydown event for enter is not triggering for ListView when Enter key is pressed. Instead, it is opening the first item of the ListView

Comment: Is it possible to override the default behaviour of ListView for Enter key press?

Comment: I guess you mean selecting the first item with "opening the first item... If you perform this on the ListView itself, it should work to navigate to another page. However, you have to take into account that if no item is preselected(for example with the arrow keys), it will always go into the first item. If another one is selected, it should use this item.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent that "default opening" behaviour for Enter key from happening? Like even if I press Enter key, nothing should happen. Then I can attach my custom logic to it.

Comment: normally, it should be good to just add your code. If not, a more detailed view on your ListView XAML would help to identify the cause of this behavior.

Comment: I am wondering how your custom logic differs from the default behavior (which is a good one as users are used to it). The only way to achieve your goal is to create your own ListView, derived from the standard one and overwrite the events that handle it.